# .NET ReactiveExtensions: Use Sample() with variable timespan

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

Given a high-frequency observable stream of data, i want to only emit an item every XX seconds.

This is usually done in RX by using .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(XX))

However... I want the time-interval to vary based on some property on the data.

Let's say my data is:

class Position
{
  ...
  public int Speed;
}

If Speed is less than 100, I want to emit data every 5 seconds. If speed is hight than 100 it should be every 2 seonds.

Is that possible with off-the-shelf Sample() or do I need to build something myself?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a low level implementation, utilizing the `System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.SchedulePeriodic` extension method as a timer.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Sample<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TimeSpan> intervalSelector, IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (intervalSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(intervalSelector));
    scheduler = scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default;

    return Observable.Create<TSource>(observer =>
    {
        TimeSpan currentInterval = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
        IDisposable timer = null;
        TSource latestItem = default;
        bool latestEmitted = true;
        object locker = new object();

        Action periodicAction = () =>
        {
            TSource itemToEmit;
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (latestEmitted) return;
                itemToEmit = latestItem;
                latestItem = default;
                latestEmitted = true;
            }
            observer.OnNext(itemToEmit);
        };

        return source.Subscribe(onNext: item =>
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                latestItem = item;
                latestEmitted = false;
            }
            var newInterval = intervalSelector(item);
            if (newInterval != currentInterval)
            {
                timer?.Dispose();
                timer = scheduler.SchedulePeriodic(newInterval, periodicAction);
                currentInterval = newInterval;
            }
        }, onError: ex =>
        {
            timer?.Dispose();
            observer.OnError(ex);
        }, onCompleted: () =>
        {
            timer?.Dispose();
            observer.OnCompleted();
        });
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
observable.Sample(x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x.Speed < 100 ? 5.0 : 2.0));
```

The timer is restarted every time the `intervalSelector` callback returns a different interval. In the extreme case that the interval is changed with every new item, then this custom operator will behave more like the built-in [`Throttle`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html) than the built-in [`Sample`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html).

> Unlike `Sample`, `Throttle`'s period is a sliding window. Each time `Throttle` receives a value, the window is reset. ([citation](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Throttle))

Comment: @CarstenGehling my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works:

```
var query =
    source
        .Publish(ss =>
            ss
                .Select(s => s.Speed < 100 ? 5.0 : 2.0)
                .Distinct()
                .Select(x => ss.Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x))));
```